# Math.random() in Java

Tags: java, math, random

I have 2 classes in the same project and I'm using `Math.random()` in both of them.
In the first all works fine, but at the second it says that `random()` is undefined.
"The method `random()` is undefined for the type Math"

Any solutions?

Comment: show some code? did you import Math ?

Comment: Do you have a class of your own called Math?

Comment: I don't think that code is relevent right now.
But I didn't import Math at the first.
I can import, but I want to understand how it works without the import...

Comment: @EJP Yes, why are you asking?

Comment: Java is a word and not an acronym

Comment: Math is part of java.lang which is a fundamental package. It does not require an import statement.

Comment: Which class have you imported the `Math` class and which class is giving you the error? as @MaxAlexander has said its by default included and you do not need to import it. I presume you have imported your implementation on the `Math` class in the class that is giving that error.

Comment: If you had showed your code the answer would have been obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call

`java.lang.Math.random()` cause your class name is also Math, so you have to specify package.

Example :

```
public class Math {

    public static void main(String args []){
        System.out.println("JDK MATH RANDOM " +java.lang.Math.random()); // refers to java.lang
        System.out.println("My Math random implementation "+Math.random()); // refers to this class method, actually Math is redundant in this scope
    }

   public static double random(){
     //some implementation
   }

}
```

Comment: Strange example. Not much point in calling the method if you're not going to save the result.

Comment: I just noticed that Math.random() stoped working right after I created another class in the same project.
Thanks!

Comment: @EJP it just an example refering to the OP ,is a package problem, i show the 2 alternatives i think is a good example to realize what is the problem, and for comment above i think it works :)

Comment: It doesn't do anything. How hard is it to edit in a result variable?

Comment: @EJP i edited but i disagree i think that last example was better cause it was more clearly,now has code that is not relevant to understand the package problem..

Answer (score 1):

If you have a class of your own called Math you have to disambiguate which one you're talking about at the point of use, e.g. Java.lang.Math.random(). The simpler option is to change the name of your class. It's bad practice to reuse names from the JDK, especially from the java.lang package.